# How can I deploy and execute an application on a device connected to a remote system?

Tags: android, adb, android-testing

I have a requirement to deploy a test application and issue commands on a device connected to another machine in the same network.

I read through http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#directingcommands but I am not able to find the answer.

I tried using `adb connect <remote machine IP>` but I got `unable to connect` error.

Is there a way to deploy applications and execute `adb` commands on a device connected to a remote system?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the `adb` [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info):

> Android Debug Bridge (adb) is a versatile command line tool that lets
>   you communicate with an emulator instance or connected Android-powered
>   device. It is a client-server program that includes three components:
>
> 1. A client, which runs on your development machine. You can invoke a client from a shell by issuing an adb command. Other Android tools such as the ADT plugin and DDMS also create adb clients.
> 2. A server, which runs as a background process on your development machine. The server manages communication between the client and the adb daemon running on an emulator or device.
> 3. A daemon, which runs as a background process on each emulator or device instance.

---

`adb connect` command is used to connect the local `adb` *server* with the `adbd` *daemon* on a network connected device. But what you want is to connect the local `adb` *client* to the remote (running on another system) `adb` *server*. The default behavior of the `adb` executable is to connect to the local instance of the `adb` *server*. If none found it would try to start one. This approach works great for most environments where all development is being done on a single system. But in more complicated environments it may result in multiple instances of `adb` *server* being launched. And because `adbd` *daemon* only supports being connected to a single `adb` server at a time - the device will get recognized by one system and will appear missing everywhere else.

So in order for `adb` to reliably recognize devices in those more complicated  configurations you need to tell `adb` to stop guessing and manually specify which part of `adb` (i.e. *server* or *client*) should be running on which system.

First off make sure that you have the same and sufficiently recent version of `adb` (the latest Google official version usually works the best) installed on both local and remote systems. And that no `adb` servers are currently running on either system.

Then start an instance of the `adb server` on the remote system (the one which you will be plugging the devices into) with this command:

```
adb -a -P <PORT_NUMBER> nodaemon server
```

Now you can force `adb` client on the local system to use the other (remote) server instead of starting its own (local) instance by adding `-H <REMOTE_IP> -P <PORT_NUMBER>` to your `adb` commands:

```
adb -H <REMOTE_IP> -P <PORT_NUMBER> devices
```

Alternatively, setting `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS=<REMOTE_IP>` and `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=<PORT_NUMBER>` environment variables on the client side would allow you to avoid having to specify the `<REMOTE_IP>` and `<PORT_NUMBER>` for every `adb` command.

And if omitted the `<PORT_NUMBER>` would default to `5037`.

This official *built-in* solution for `adb` orchestration is not a mutually exclusive alternative to the *SSH tunneling* - it just addresses another more important issue. You can add tunneling on top of this to add extra security or help with routing issues in a multi site network environment. But the tunneling alone will not be able to solve all the `adb` connectivity problems.

Same goes for the virtualized environments - running multiple `adb server` instances between *host* and *guest* systems will also result in the `adb` connectivity issues.

Comment: Thanks this helped. We can also create AVDs on a machine (or connected devices) and then use andriod-platform tools to connect to AVDs

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it makes it seem like my goal isn't impossible anymore. Does anyone have an idea how to integrate this solution into Android Studio though?

Comment: This is one of those answers I whish I could upvote multiple times. Exactly what I needed, and thanks for the info on the environment variables. One catch though - It seems *both computers need to be running the same version of ADB*.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help:

Its a java library that I've developed few months ago specifically with that remote adb commands in mind. The basic idea was to provide some abstraction layer where devices could be similarly accessed on remote machine as it was locally connected. Check it out:

https://github.com/lesavsoftware/rem-adb-exec

PS. and it uses SSH tunnel so it should be secure enough.

Answer (score 1):

What about using SSH to connect to the machine on which your device is attached and issue ADB command from there ?
This is at least what we do in our company where we have dozens of devices we control like that.

Answer (score 1):

With Android Studio, it attempts connect to localhost.
Try set ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS,ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT
and in console:
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT connectaddress=ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS
and connect manually (with studio external tools) to adb