# Remote debugging an android application

Tags: android, debugging, adb, remote-debugging

I'm having a two systems[System A, System B] each connected via wifi . Each system has got android studio installed. Is it possible by any means that I can run my app on System B while using System A for development? In short, I wanna access the system B's emulator  from system A and run my app.  I don't want to try this with blue stacks or any other alternatives. I tried to access the system B 's emulator through adb so as to do wifi debugging using an emulator but it is not working. are there any other alternatives? FYI, System A is Mac that Im using for development and System B which will be running the emulator is ubuntu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27256599/1778421

Answer (score 0):

Is it just to view the logs live? You could acheive this by opening adb on system A and redirecting the output to a text file, which you can open on system B.

To do that (Unix)

system A

```
cd /mnt/networkshare/dev/
adb logcat > logs.txt
```

system B

```
gedit /mnt/networkshare/dev/logs.txt
```

Comment: no...not to view logs...i want to run the entire app in system b's emulator.

Comment: Your best bet then is to learn and use Git.

You could then develop the app on System A, push updates on Git, download updates from B and then run the emulator on B.

Comment: I want that to be run without using git just like we do in wifi debugging

Comment: To be sure:  
You want emulator B to run an app, while system A develops it.  
You also want the logs to be routed on system A.  
You also want to send a precompiled app from system A to system B and make it run.  
You might even want to attach the emulator B to the system A.  

First two ponts could be done with this answers.  
Last two are out of my knowledge radius.  

Sorry i can't be helpful then, got lured by "remote debugging" :)