# Can Multiple ADB Clients Connect to a Single Android ADBD over Wireless

Tags: android, adb, adbwireless

I have a single Android device that is running adb in TCP mode.

I connect one client use 
adb connect localhost:XYZ 
and it works fine.

Meanwhile, I connect a 2nd client on a separate computer
adb connect localhost:XYZ

Adb devices shows it as offline, is this a known limitation?

Answer (score 1):

`adb` clients do not connect to `adbd` (daemon running on Android device) directly. They connect through `adb` server which does the multiplexing.

Yes current `adb` design only supports one `adb` server connection per `adbd`.

If you need to send `adb` commands from another PC - just send it through the `adb` server running on the 1st PC (the one already connected to the device)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256599/1778421) shows how it can be done.