# Android Studio, connect to a device that is attached to a remote computer?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

- Computer 1: Running Android Studio.
- Computer 2: An Android device is attached via USB.

Can I make the Android Studio use the Android device for debugging just as I can do with a locally connected device? The Android device is not rooted, so Wi-Fi ADB connection from Computer 1 to the device is not possible.

Comment: The only way I see is to use debug through WiFi

Comment: That is a disappointment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27245597/1778421

Comment: @Alex P. I browsed the answer in the link above, though I have not tested it yet. But, does that work with Android Studio, or does it only work with manuall adb commands on the Command Prompt?