# Multiple adb connections over WiFi

Tags: android, adb

We are two people and want to connect to a `android device` from each respective notebook. When one person is connected, the other person gets a `device is offline` error.

Is it possible to connect via `adb shell` to a single `android device` from multiple machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 parts to `adb`:

1. *daemon* (runs on a device)
2. *server* (runs on a host PC)
3. *client* (usually runs on the same host PC as server)

As it currently stands, the *daemon* allows only 1 connection from a *server* at the time. It is the *server* part which does the multiplexing and allows multiple *clients* run multiple commands simultaneously.

In your case instead of every person trying to run their own *server* - let one person to run the *server* and the other one use that *server* remotely like I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256599/1778421).