# Can we pass through a USB device to a Docker container on Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, adb

I'm trying to access ADB from Docker images running on a Ubuntu host machine, but it doesn't work. Is it possible to access an ADB device through Docker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42375902/1778421

Comment: run `adb server` on the host and `adb clients` inside containers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256599/1778421

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper network setup. Running Docker with `--network host` is the easiest, but the least safe way.