# Failed to execute adb -a -P 5037 fork-server server

Tags: adb

5037 is not occupied and the error message is reply fd for adb server to client communication not specified. The version of adb is 1.0.39. I want to share port for STF Provider. Appreciate for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256599/1778421

Comment: It works for me. Run "adb -a -P 5037 daemon" in windows, then "stf provider --adb-host ip -port 5037" can find my devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Moon said in his comment: the solution is to run

```
adb -a -P 5037 daemon
```

and then

```
stf provider --adb-host ip -port 5037
```