# Device not listed by adb devices on a virtual machine guest

Tags: android, linux, adb, virtualbox

Why is my android phone not listed by `adb devices`?

I followed instructions described at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device but ADB still doesn't find my device.
My user is already member of `plugdev` group. I also have tried to kill and restart the `adb` server.

I'm running Debian Stretch in a VirtualBox machine. Debian can see my device but `adb` can't.

```
eduardo@debian:~$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1004:633e LG Electronics, Inc. GZ Android Phone [MTP mode]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub    
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8oee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet    
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

eduardo@debian:~$ ls -l /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

-rw-r-r- 1 root root 4611 Sep 5 15:25 /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

eduardo@debian:~$ grep 1004 /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRfidVendor1=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="p1ugdev"

eduardo@debian:~$ adb devices

List of devices attached

eduardo@debian:~$
```

Comment: Did you enable [developer options and enable debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) on your device?

Comment: Debug mode is enabled. Rebooted device and host machine. Still doesn't list.

Comment: I'm not sure ADB works within a VM, even if the device is seen.

Comment: please do not use screen shots of text

Comment: @AlexP. Ok. Removed.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to use `adb` in a virtualized environment regardless of the specific platforms is to run `adb server` on the host as a remote system and run `adb` clients inside the guest systems. See [my answer to another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256599/1778421) .

While it is possible to run both the server and the clients completely inside of guest system, to do so reliably usually involves passing through the whole USB controller into the guest system.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround that solved my problem. It is not perfect but it works.

1. Disable bridging USB to VirtualBox machine
2. Install platform-tools on host machine and run `adb devices`
3. Authorize your computer on device screen
4. In the virtual machine make a tcp tunnel that redirects local port 5037 to the host machine 5037 port:

   `ssh -L 5037:10.0.2.2:5037 localhost -N -f`

I'm not going to mark this as the correct answer because my Guest ADB still doesn't see my device

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I changed my device USB to charge only mode.

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/632668

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurs most likely because the MTP device was still used when the redirection of the device to the VM was requested. You didn't specify your host OS, so I will describe the steps to verify this on a Linux host.

Just type `lsof /dev/libmtp-{number}` (where `{number}` is the kernel number assigned to the device) to list the processes having an open file descriptor to the device file. If you have multiple devices you can find the name of the device via `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/{number}/product`. The output should show an indication that the device is in use (e.g. `gvfsd-mtp` in gnome environments). (If there is no process listed, then your problem seems to be a bug that can have various reasons.)

The solution is to remove all the uses of the device. This could be done by simply killing the processes with `kill {PID}` where `{PID}` is the process id taken from the output of the previous `lsof` command. **ATTENTION**: Kill a process only in own responsibility. But in case of gvfsd-mtp (gnome environment) you can unmount the MTP device with `gio mount -u /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\={manufacturer}_{product}_{serial}`.