# Is it possible to debug an app with a device connected on a remote network?

Tags: java, android, adb

There's an app my team is developing in Android Java using Android Studio.

The app works alright on all our test devices, however it shows some bugs on the client's device.

Is it possible to somehow connect the client's device to his network and make this device available on a developer machine for debugging over the internet?

It was pointed to me that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245597/how-can-i-deploy-and-execute-an-application-on-a-device-connected-to-a-remote-sy) already answers my question. I agree that it does in part; it teaches how to connect the client adb to the adb server on a remote network. Still, can I use Android Studio to debug the phone?

Maybe VPN can be used? I don't know much about VPNs, so suggestions of which would work would be awesome.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use Crashlytics : https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sofiane, however the bug we are seeing does not crash the app, so we have to try to debug it to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is pretty dangerous, as exposing the debugging bridge of your personal device to the internet could prove problematic and unsafe for your personal data.**

That aside, the only way I could see this working would be if the client were to port forward the debugging port to the IP address of their device (this would need to be completed on their router)

By default I believe the port to be 5037.

Once the port is forwarded, you *should* be able to connect to that device in particular by using

```
adb connect <their external IP>
```

**Again, I cannot stress enough how dangerous this could potentially be.**

Comment: Thank you keag. Can I connect using Android Studio for debugging?

Comment: ADB is the utility used for making these debugging connections. Its used internally by android studio to handle connections, but I don't believe it allows you to make connections to specific IP addresses. When I want to do that, I use a windows command prompt to run the command I specified above. The ADB utility can be installed from this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Comment: Once you have made the ADB connection using the command line utility, the connection will be available to your whole system. Android Studio will see it as a debuggable device.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!