# cant recognize usb on virtual box guest with ubuntu , while host is windows 10

Tags: android, usb, virtualbox

I'm working on windows 10 as host, with guest virtual box with ubuntu 18.04
I have my android mobile connected to usb and when running from windows (cmd) "adb devices" i see my devices.
Now, i want to work on the device (develop automation on it) from the oracle virtual box (ver 6.0.0.)

I install the usb extention to virtual box, choose in setting >usb>usb3 , checked the "eanble usb controller" and add to usb device filters my phone from the list.
I logged in to my ubuntu, cannot see the mobile detected, i run adb devices and get nothing, and also run  "vboxmanage list usbhost" and get nothing.
Tried already every guide on net, but nothing helped
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256599/1778421

Comment: Checking -Thank you

Comment: Later on ill be using appium?is this solution going to support it?

Comment: it works -Thanks a lot !